# LocalDate format in Get request JAVA

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, get, localdate

I'm writing a REST interface for my Java MVC app. Here is one function:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/restaurant_representation", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RestaurantRepresentation restaurantRepresent(
        @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) LocalDate date,
        @RequestParam(value = "id") Integer id) {
            return date == null ?
                restaurantRepresentationCompiler.compileRestaurantRepresentation(id, LocalDate.now()) :
                restaurantRepresentationCompiler.compileRestaurantRepresentation(id, date);
    }
```

Now I'm testing this, and

> /rest/admin/restaurant_representation?id=1004

this requst provides a correct result, but when I try to add date parameter

> /rest/admin/restaurant_representation?date=2015-05-05&id=1004

it showes this:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

What LocalDate format is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`

like this:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/restaurant_representation", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RestaurantRepresentation restaurantRepresent(
        @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date,
        @RequestParam(value = "id") Integer id) {
            return date == null ?
                restaurantRepresentationCompiler.compileRestaurantRepresentation(id, LocalDate.now()) :
                restaurantRepresentationCompiler.compileRestaurantRepresentation(id, date);
}
```

Comment: you beat me to an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `@DateTimeFormat` and specify the format of the date that you're accepting.

```
@RequestParam(required = false, value = "date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate fromDate
```